# SQL - Select records that their columns do not follow the same order

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Given we have following table where the series number and the the date should increment

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id | series |    date    |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |     10 | 2020-08-13 |
|  2 |      9 | 2020-08-02 |
|  3 |      8 | 2020-06-23 |
|  4 |      7 | 2020-06-08 |
|  5 |      6 | 2020-05-20 |
|  6 |      5 | 2020-05-05 |
|  7 |      4 | 2020-05-01 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Is there a way to check if there are records that do not follow this pattern ?
For example row 2 has bigger series number but it's date is before row 3

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id | series |    date    |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |     10 | 2020-08-13 |
|  2 |      9 | 2020-06-02 |
|  3 |      8 | 2020-07-23 |
|  4 |      7 | 2020-06-08 |
|  5 |      6 | 2020-05-20 |
|  6 |      5 | 2020-05-05 |
|  7 |      4 | 2020-05-01 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Comment: The result set doesn't correspond to the data set !?!?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lead(date) over(order by series) lead_date
    from mytable t
) t
where date > lead_date
```

Alternatively:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lead(series) over(order by date) lead_series
    from mytable t
) t
where series > lead_series
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(id) over (order by series) as prev_id_series,
             lag(id) over (order by date) as prev_id_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_id_series <> prev_id_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch problematic rows and their corresponding conflicting rows using SELF JOIN like this (assuming your table is called "series"):

```
SELECT s1.id AS row_id, s1.series AS row_series, s1.date AS row_date, 
       s2.id AS conflict_id, s2.series AS conflict_series, s2.date AS conflict_date
FROM series AS s1
JOIN series AS s2
  ON s1.series > s2.series AND s1.date < s2.date;
```